# How many columns can Spark's PCA implementation handle?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Can I compute the principal components of 1,000,000 columns, for example?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of columns is 65,535.

This limitation is enforced in RowMatrix where we see this comment:

```
This cannot be computed on matrices with more than 65535 columns
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.scala#L380